# Centos live install yum

Tags: centos

I am booting from a centos 7 live usb. I am trying to mount an NTFS filesystem, however in missing the ntfs-3g package. Attempts to use yum give an error suggesting yum is not installed - the python package for yum is present however I get the error seeing yummain module couldn't be found when running yum. I've used wget to grab the ntfs-3g package but obviously there is a dependency chain to tackle.

Is there a way to get yum working on the live usb to handle all this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so looks like the required packages are in /run/install/repo/Packages

Unfortunately the dependencies take up a lot of space and therefore is probably why yum isn't installed on the live usb by default.

It is possible to install yum this way, as the dependencies should all be in the above location.

Answer (score 0):

You can install it with `rpm` command:

```
rpm -i https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/7/x86_64/Packages/n/ntfs-3g-2017.3.23-11.el7.x86_64.rpm
```

You can try to install only `yum` from rpm on the same way:

```
rpm -i http://your_centos_mirror/7/os/x86_64/Packages/yum-3.4.3-161.el7.centos.noarch.rpm
```

Comment: This is what I went for, but as per my question, I was wanting a way around the huge dependency chain. In sure the installer has the correct packages for yum somewhere, but I'm not sure where.

Comment: @JamoBox, install `yum` via `rpm`

Comment: Yes.. but this also has a dependency chain. I'm really after a way to get yum working with what's already on the live usb. I'm happy with the answer being "it's not possible" but I'm not after downloading tens of different rpms manually typing URLs by hand.

Comment: Right, @JamoBox and this is the reason `yum` was created. You can try and install one by one dependencies...

Comment: Yes of course. As per my own answer the 'whats already on the USB' solves this. The dependency chain of packages already exist on the USB, so it's fairly trivial from there.